# How to Pass incoming params with redirect_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a neophyte to Ruby On Rails (3). Using Get and Post, I'm trying to create a simple login functionality.
After the login credentials are SUBMITed, I've written the following code in my controller,

def login
  @title = "Test Login"

```
 if request.post? and params[:user]
   @user = User.new(params[:user])
   user = User.find_by_username_and_password(@user.username , @user.password)

if user
   session[:user_id] = user.id
   flash[:notice] = "User #{user.username} logged in!"

   redirect_to :action => "index" , :username => params[:username]
```

The problem lies here, I want to print the name that was entered in the username textfield.
Hence, I'm redirecting it to index along with params. Please help me, get my syntax right, inorder to transfer the username parameter to index with redirect_to.

Comment: No error at all !! It Just displays username.. This how I'm trying to display it in index.html.erb. >> file <%= :username %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work.

Is the code giving you an error?

---

Updated from data.

Think I got what is happening. It is how you are trying to display it.

First inside your index method you need a line such as

```
@username = params[:username]
```

the @username will make the variable available to your index.html.erb file as it becomes an instance variable for the controller.

In index.html.erb

```
Welcome Back <%= @usename %>
```

That should do it.

Comment: What is the log showing? Or if you are running the server from rails s what is showing up then?

Comment: No error at all !! It displays just   >   username
This how I'm trying to display it in index.html.erb file
<%= :username %>

Comment: SERVER LOG >>>>   
Processing by UserController#index as HTML  
  Parameters: {"username"=>"agent1"}

Comment: That is what it read in the log.

It is properly passing the entered name "agent1".

But displays username.

Comment: Updated the answer.  I think it's how you are doing the display in the erb file and of course making sure the variable is available for it.

Comment: @huntsfromshadow : Voila! That was spot on..! Its working just perfect.. Thanks a ton mate. God Bless U :)